# How to hide free shipping for user group

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, shipping, group

I inherited a highly customized Magento-store. One of the modifications was to hide the `free shipping` method from one of the customer groups at checkout. I want to undo this modification, so all customer groups can see free shipping as per the default set up. The problem is, I can't seem to find where the modification has been made. I have checked in the template `app/design/frontend...` and in Shipping, `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping`  . I didn't find any modifications in any files there that would cause this behavior.

> Where would a modification to hide a shipping method from a user group
>   on checkout have been made?

Comment: It wouldn't be in Magento's core files. I would start by looking at the names of the various modules located in `app/code/local` and `app/code/community` and see if a descriptive module name could at least get you on the right track. Once you determine the module that might possibly be the one, look inside of the config.xml at all of the `observers`. There may be one also named descriptively.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by overwrite your free shipping carrier file app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

`Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping`

You will need to check in `collectRates` function that your logged in customer is from your specific customer group or not.

You can add below code just after

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
    return false;
}

if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if ($customer->getGroupId() == 1) { // this is for general customer group, you can add your specific customer group for which you want to restrict free shipping method.
        return false;
    }
}
```